# Add subwindow inside QPlainTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt5

How to add a subwindow inside `QPlainTextEdit`?
I try it:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    this->setFixedSize(800,600);
    mainW = new QWidget(this);
    mainW->setGeometry(0,0, 800, 600);
    QGridLayout* lay = new QGridLayout(mainW);
    QPlainTextEdit* te = new QPlainTextEdit(mainW);
    QPlainTextEdit* te2 = new QPlainTextEdit(mainW);
    mdiArea = new QMdiArea(te);
    QWidget *widget = new QWidget(mdiArea);
    QGridLayout *gridLayout = new QGridLayout(widget);
    widget->setLayout(gridLayout);
    QLabel *label = new QLabel("Hello, I am sub window!!!", widget);
    gridLayout->addWidget(label);
    mdiArea->addSubWindow(widget);
    widget->setWindowTitle("Sub Window");
    widget->show();
}
```

[image]

Layout of subwindow overlaps a `QPlainTextEdit`. How can you avoid this?

Comment: Please have a look at the documentation for [`QMainWindow`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html).  The child widget hierarchy you need should be created and then set using [`QMainWindow::setCentralWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget).

Comment: @G.M. It's not work. The same thing happens.